# Python3.5 function that calls object's method returns None instead of object

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I have a class and a function that tries to update and return instances of this class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datum = 'a'
    def update(self):
        self.datum = 'b' if self.datum == 'a' else 'a'

def updater(foo_obj):
    return( foo_obj.update() )
```

but calling `updater()` returns `None`s and not instances of class `Foo`. Why is this? What can I change to get the desired result?

```
type(updater(Foo())) #NoneType
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `Foo.update`.

Comment: See my comment below on Dipak's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update method updater.

```
def updater(foo_obj):
    foo_obj.update()
    return( foo_obj )
```

OR `return self` from class function:

```
def update(self):
        self.datum = 'b' if self.datum == 'a' else 'a'
        return self
```

Comment: The first one is what I wanted. Why does splitting it up into two lines totally change the effect?

Comment: @Taylor Because then you're returning the object itself, not the return value of `.update()`, which is `None`.

Comment: yeah, makes sense. I feel stupid for not having run into this before.

Answer (score 1):

Your `update` method does not return anything, which in Python means that it implicitly returns `None`. If you want it to have a meaningful return value, you'd have to do so explicitly. E.g.:

```
def update(self):
    self.datum = 'b' if self.datum == 'a' else 'a'
    return self.datum
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like `update` to return instances of the `Foo` class, you have to explicitly have it do so with a return statement, otherwise it will implicitly return `None` (i.e. it's a void method, even though Python doesn't use these terms because duck-typing). Do this like so:

```
def update(self):
    self.datum = 'b' if self.datum == 'a' else 'a'
    return self
```

You could also return the `Foo` object in `updater` if you don't want your class to do it, like so:

```
def updater(foo_obj):
    foo_obj.update()
    return foo_obj
```

If you'd like to return just `self.datum` and not the whole object, then do that like:

```
def update(self):
    self.datum = 'b' if self.datum == 'a' else 'a'
    return self.datum
```

or similarly:

```
def updater(foo_obj):
    foo_obj.update()
    return foo_obj.datum
```